# The principle of java calendar add()?

Tags: java, algorithm, date, time

Given a date(denoted as date1), what's the algorithm that java takes in function add() to calculate the date after n days(denoted as date2)? Is there a formula or an O(1) algorithm?

PS:
I've just understood the method that linux takes to calculate the gap between current date(y-m-d) and the reference date(usually 1970-1-1), and I've generalized this method to calculate the gap between any couple of days,just as the following codes writes:

```
int gapBetween(int y1, int m1, int d1, int y2, int m2, int d2)
{
    m1 -= 2, m2 -= 2;
    if (m1 <= 0)
        m1 += 12, y1--;
    if (m2 <= 0)
        m2 += 12, y2--;

    int p1 = 367 * m1 / 12 - 30 + d1;
    int p2 = (y2 - y1) * 365;
    int p3 = 367 * m2 / 12 - 30 + d2;
    int p4 = (y2 / 4 - y2 / 100 + y2 / 400) - (y1 / 4 - y1 / 100 + y1 / 400);
    return p2 - p1 + p3 + p4;
}
```

Naturally,I want to know that if I was given a date(denoted as date1) and an integer n, is there a similar method to calculate the date(denoted as date2) that n days after date1? I've thought for a while but got stucked. After searching in the internet, I found the member function add() in class calendar in java can do this job, but I haven't found more detail about this function.Can anybody tell me where to find relevant information? thks~

Comment: Yes, I'd like to know the O(1) solution behind this problem.

Comment: Java is open source so you could check the code of `GregorianCalendar` to see how that is implemented.

Comment: Be aware that the old date-time classes java.util.Date/.Calendar/.GregorianCalendar have been supplanted by the java.time framework built into Java 8 and later. You should be looking at the `LocalDate` or `ZonedDateTime` classes.